# Rewrite to index.php maintaining query parameters

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, slim

I'm trying to configure my Nginx vhost to rewrite all requests to `/index.php` as is standard with frameworks, but I don't think Nginx is passing the correct parts of the URI through in the `$_SERVER` superglobal.

I can rewrite `/foo/bar` to `/index.php/foo/bar` and the route works fine, but if I append query parameters the route fails because the query parameters appear to be included in the `REQUEST_URI` field, which they should not be. For example, navigating to `http://lts3/test?foo=bar` returns a 404 error from Slim.

Here's the result of `print_r($_SERVER)` for a query string containing parameters (`http://lts3/test?foo=bar`), which breaks:

```
Array
(
    [USER] => www-data
    [HOME] => /var/www
    [FCGI_ROLE] => RESPONDER
    [QUERY_STRING] => /test?foo=bar
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [CONTENT_TYPE] => 
    [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /var/www/lts3/public/index.php
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_URI] => /test?foo=bar
    [DOCUMENT_URI] => /index.php
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /var/www/lts3/public
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => nginx/1.4.1
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 192.168.1.134
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 58050
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 192.168.1.113
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [SERVER_NAME] => lts3
    [HTTPS] => 
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [PHP_VALUE] => include_path=.:/var/www/lts3:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear
    [SITEMODE] => development
    [HTTP_HOST] => lts3
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.76 Safari/537.36
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate,sdch
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-GB,en;q=0.8
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1390079833.408
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1390079833
)
```

And here's my Nginx virtual host:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name lts3;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/lts3-error.log;

        root /var/www/lts3/public;

        location / {
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri /index.php?$request_uri;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "include_path=.:/var/www/lts3:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear";
                fastcgi_param SITEMODE development;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
}
```

Why are `QUERY_STRING` and `REQUEST_URI` identical, and how can I configure my Nginx vhost to pass the correct part of the URI to each one? It is my understanding that `REQUEST_URI` should contain only `/test`, and `QUERY_STRING` should contain `foo=bar`. I've tried various different rewrite rules, none of which had any positive effect. I'm going round in circles now.

I have attempted solutions found [here](http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/problems/4204-cannot-get-url-parametersquery-string), [here](http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/show-and-tell/209-sample-nginx-config) and [here](http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/problems/1487-nginx-slimframework), all to no avail. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: use `/index.php?$request_uri$is_args$query_string` if you want to append the real query string, in the `try_files`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add
`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` like I did below. I also modified your `try_files` line.

You also may want to include a path to your rewrites (which I commented out). I hope this helps...

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name lts3;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/lts3-error.log;

        root /var/www/lts3/public;

        location / {
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
        }

        # Optional Line (un-comment to use):
        # include /path/to/rewrites.conf;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "include_path=.:/var/www/lts3:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear";
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param SITEMODE development;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
        }
}
```

Once you include your rewrites you can then add a rewrite rule like this:

```
rewrite /(.+)/(.+) /index.php?$1=$2;
```